# Reading a local JSON file from Angular/Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have tried placing an `en.json` file in the following locations:

```
src/assets/i18n/en.json
src/app/assets/i18n/en.json
```

And I then try to read the file like this:

```
import {knownFolders, File} from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class TranslateFileLoader implements TranslateLoader {
    constructor(public prefix: string = 'assets/i18n/', public suffix: string = '.json') {}

    public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<Object> {
      const appFolder = knownFolders.currentApp(); // Havet tried with knownFolders.documents() also
      console.log(`${this.prefix}${lang}${this.suffix}`);
      const cfgFile = appFolder.getFile(`${this.prefix}${lang}${this.suffix}`);
      console.log(File.exists(cfgFile.path));
      console.log(cfgFile.path);
      const fileData = cfgFile.readTextSync();
      console.log(fileData);
      return JSON.parse(fileData);
    }
}
```

> console.log #1: assets/i18n/en.json
>  console.log #2: true
>   console.log #3:
>   /data/data/org.nativescript.playground/files/app/assets/i18n/en.json
>   console.log #4:

So yeah, the path seems good, the `File.exists(cfgFile.path)` returns `true`, but the `fileData` is empty and thus I get a exception when I `JSON.parse(fileData)`. But why? First I thought that the files where not there, but I get true from my exists test. So it seems that the file is there when the device/emulator is running, but I can not read its content?

Any ideas?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Use 'HttpClient' to read json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it! HttpClient does not work on Native (yes my problem was with Nativescript on native devices, where there are no http server serving the files, and yes there I do have access to local storage). My code worked, but the *.json files was not transferred to the build packages. I had to add those in mt webpack.config.js in the tns part of "CopyWebpackPlugin", then it all worked :) I could not thrust the "File.exists" because my call to ".getFile" created a empty file.

Comment: can you give a hint what to modify here exactly? I extended the array, but my files are still not getting copied.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the playground example so it may be easy to identify where the issue is. Between you may even simply import the JSON as.

For example, **en.ts**

```
export const languageJSON = {
   ....
};
```

Import it as

```
const languageJSON = require(`${this.prefix}${lang}${this.suffix}`).languageJSON;
```

Since the path is dynamic, just make sure your webpack build understands it.

Comment: It works with NativeScript. I use it day to day app development 

Answer (score 0):

Think of it the environment you are running your JS code.

If you are running under node.js your code makes sense and it will work.

if you are running in a browser, for security reasons the local file system is out of reach. However you should are able to fetch files from the server, as well you might be able to write and read from a local sandbox.

However there is this API, see if it works for you:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API

In my projects I often store localization in json files and I successfully fetch them with :

```
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  ..
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 
  ..
  this.http.get(this.urlToFile, { responseType: 'wherever you need here text|json'}).map(res => {...});
```

Comment: I agree with you if it's a browser environment but as he tagged, it's NativeScript Angular and you will have access to file system too.